# How do I .map() over JSON data within multiple levels of array that I receive from end point?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to display weather api data from: (https://www.weatherapi.com/api-explorer.aspx#forecast)

```
import Image from "next/image"

interface Hour {
    time_epoch: number
    time: string
    temp_c: number
    temp_f: number
    is_day: number
    wind_mph: number
    wind_kph: number
    wind_degree: number
    wind_dir: string
    pressure_mb: number
    pressure_in: number
    precip_mm: number
    precip_in: number
    humidity: number
    cloud: number
    feelslike_c: number
    feelslike_f: number
    windchill_c: number
    windchill_f: number
    heatindex_c: number
    heatindex_f: number
    dewpoint_c: number
    dewpoint_f: number
    will_it_rain: number
    chance_of_rain: number
    will_it_snow: number
    chance_of_snow: number
    vis_km: number
    vis_miles: number
    gust_mph: number
    gust_kph: number
}


async function getHourlyForecast() {
  const location = 'Pemberton'
  const apiKey = '84703323c7f94238a98203306233010'
  const response = await fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=${apiKey}&q=${location}&days=1&aqi=no&alerts=no` , {
    cache: 'no-cache',})
  const data = await response.json()
  return data 
}

export default async function Forecast() {
  const forecast = await getHourlyForecast()
  console.log(forecast);

  return (
     <div>
        <h2 className="text-center">Hourly Weather Forecast</h2>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-7 gap-6">
        {forecast.forecastday.map((hour, index) => 
        (
          <div key={index} className="text-center rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center bg-green-950/25 p-10">
            <p>{new Date(hour.date).toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: "short"})}</p>
            <img className="w-50 h-50"
              src={hour.hour.condition.icon}
              alt={hour.hour.condition.text}
              aria-label={hour.hour.condition.text}/>
            <div>
              <p className="bg-black/25 px-2 italic rounded-xl text-white mb-2">
                High:{" "}
                <span aria-label={`Maximum temperature: ${hour.hour.temp_c.toFixed()} degrees Celcius`}>
                  {hour.hour.maxtemp_c.toFixed()}°
                </span>
              </p>
              <p className="bg-black/25 px-2 italic rounded-xl text-white">
                Low:{" "}
                <span aria-label={`Minimum temperature: ${hour.hour.temp_c.toFixed()} degrees Celcius`}>
                  {hour.hour.temp_c.toFixed()}°
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        </div>
    </div>
   
  );
}
```

I am able to map data from Forecast.Current but I also want to map from Forecast.Forecastday.Day object but object comes back as undefined.
Can anyone help?

Tried:  {forecast.forecastday.map((hour, index) =>
but got undefined.

Comment: can you post the shape of the forecast object? That link you posted to the API explorer seems to need an API key or something.

Comment: http://jsonblob.com/1172378514321432576

Comment: i am trying to grab hourly weather data and display each hour in its own div. I was able to do it with daily weather data.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code.

```
export default async function Forecast() {
  const forecast = await getHourlyForecast();
  console.log(forecast);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="text-center">Hourly Weather Forecast</h2>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-7 gap-6">
        {forecast.forecast.forecastday.map((day, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="text-center rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center bg-green-950/25 p-10">
            <p>{new Date(day.date).toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })}</p>
            <img
              className="w-50 h-50"
              src={day.day.condition.icon}
              alt={day.day.condition.text}
              aria-label={day.day.condition.text}
            />
            <div>
              <p className="bg-black/25 px-2 italic rounded-xl text-white mb-2">
                High:{" "}
                <span aria-label={`Maximum temperature: ${day.day.maxtemp_c.toFixed()} degrees Celsius`}>
                  {day.day.maxtemp_c.toFixed()}
                </span>
              </p>
              <p className="bg-black/25 px-2 italic rounded-xl text-white">
                Low:{" "}
                <span aria-label={`Minimum temperature: ${day.day.mintemp_c.toFixed()} degrees Celsius`}>
                  {day.day.mintemp_c.toFixed()}
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

One suggestion - If this component is rerendering frequently with the same data, you may use React Hook - **`useMemo`** to memoize the forecast data and avoid unnecessary re-renders. Please tell me if that works.

Comment: export default async function Forecast() {
  const forecast = await getHourlyForecast()

  return (
      <div>
          {forecast.forecast.forecastday.map((hour, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}><p>{hour.hour.temp_c}</p></div>
            )
          })}
      </div>
  )
}

Answer (score 0):

To map over the forecastday and its nested properties, you need to make sure that each level of nesting exists and is not undefined.

**EXAMPLE**

```
export default async function Forecast() {
  const forecast = await getHourlyForecast();
  console.log(forecast);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="text-center">Hourly Weather Forecast</h2>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-7 gap-6">
        {forecast.forecastday.map((day, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="text-center rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center bg-green-950/25 p-10">
            <p>{new Date(day.date).toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: "short" })}</p>
            {/* Check if `day.hour` is an array and not undefined */}
            {day.hour && Array.isArray(day.hour) && day.hour.map((hour, hourIndex) => (
              <div key={hourIndex}>
                <img
                  className="w-50 h-50"
                  src={hour.condition.icon}
                  alt={hour.condition.text}
                  aria-label={hour.condition.text}
                />
                <div>
                  <p className="bg-black/25 px-2 italic rounded-xl text-white mb-2">
                    High:{" "}
                    <span aria-label={`Maximum temperature: ${hour.temp_c.toFixed()} degrees Celsius`}>
                      {hour.maxtemp_c.toFixed()}°
                    </span>
                  </p>
                  <p className="bg-black/25 px-2 italic rounded-xl text-white">
                    Low:{" "}
                    <span aria-label={`Minimum temperature: ${hour.temp_c.toFixed()} degrees Celsius`}>
                      {hour.temp_c.toFixed()}°
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this still throws an error:
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: I can see there is an object with keys: hour when i try to return 
Unhandled Runtime Error  (found: object with keys {date, date_epoch, day, astro, hour}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: export default async function Forecast() {
  const forecast = await getHourlyForecast()

  return (
      <div>
          {forecast.forecast.forecastday.map((hour, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}><p>{hour.hour.temp_c}</p></div>
            )
          })}
      </div>
  )
}

Comment: if i map the hour array the same as the day array i get no errors but i also get no output to the page.

Comment: I can map all the way down to {forecast.forecast.forecastday.map(hour, index)}. If i consol.log(Object.keys(forecast.forecast.forecastday.hour)) i get an array of the hours like this: "hour": {"0", "1", "3"} etc